# Ordenar dicionario e apresentar 20 primeiros

Tags: python, dicionário

Tenho um dicionario com palavras e respetiva frequência.
Do género:

```
dic = {walt: 2, disney: 1, ola: 5, ...}
```

Para ordenar o dicionário fiz desse jeito:

```
aux = sorted(dicionario, key=dicionario.get, reverse=True)
```

E para apresentar os 20 primeiros queria fazer assim, mas não ta dando.

```
while count < 20:
    maior.append(dicionario.keys()[count])
    count +=1
return maior
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walt057, acho que tenho uma solução para seu código.

**1.** Quando estamos definindo um dicionário (que é uma estrutura de dados chave: valor), podemos usar vários tipos de variáveis, seja elas: str; int; float.

Assim, constituí um dicionário à fins didáticos com algumas palavras aleatórias:

```
dictionary = {
    'walt': 2, 'disney': 1, 'ola': 5, 'teste': 12, 'you': 9, 'hasd': 6, 'asd1': 7, '91uas': 8, 'h91k': 9, '9ahsdkj': 10,
    'mais': 1, 'uma': 21, 'tchau': 8, 'mãe': 8, 'você': 6, 'computador': 12, 'mouse': 19, 'celular': 29, 'energetico': 9, 'caneta': 10,
    'vigesimo': 20, 'vigesimo primeiro': 20
}
```

Note que coloquei 22 itens, se quiser verificar o tamanho, podemos usar a função len():

```
print(len(dictionary))
```

Isso retornará o tamanho do dicionário.

**2.** Para ordenar, podemos usar um código simplificado:

```
dictionary_sorted = sorted(dictionary)
```

Isso fará com que o respectivo dicionário seja ordenado por ordem alfabética.
Usamos o key para obter uma lista das chaves do dicionário, e usamos o get para pegar o valor especifico de uma chave.

Se quiser conferir o tamanho do dicionário, ele não irá remover ou adicionar itens e continuará com o mesmo tamanho do dicionário primário.

```
print(len(dictionary_sorted))
```

O mesmo ainda terá os 22 itens.

**3.** Como deseja mostrar os 20 primeiros valores do dicionário (ordenado por meio da chave em ordem alfabética - note que o resultado será um array, visto que os dicionários não são ordenados), poderá 'fatiar' o desejado:

```
to_present = dictionary_sorted[:20]
```

O ':' é um indicador para mostrar as posições respectivas que desejamos. No caso :20 (note que não terá nada antes do :, e mostrando até onde desejamos). E como resposta, ele apresentará uma lista com as palavras.

**4.** caso deseje mostrar de uma forma simplificada, sem ter que realizar um laço de repetição, você poderá utilizar a função join():

```
print(', '.join(to_present))
```

Como resposta teremos todos os valores do to_present (que fatiamos os 20 primeiros)

```
91uas, 9ahsdkj, asd1, caneta, celular, computador, disney, energetico, h91k, hasd, mais, mouse, mãe, ola, tchau, teste, uma, vigesimo,vigesimo primeiro, você
```

Espero ter colaborado com seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Se você usou a `collections.Counter`, como sugerido em [Ordenar dicionario e adicionar valores python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/351334/5878), acredito que você não tenha se preocupado em ler a documentação. Antes de usar **qualquer** função é essencial que você leia a documentação e entenda **exatamente** o que ela faz.

O classe `Counter` possui o método `most_common` que, como o nome sugere, retorna os itens mais comuns do objeto.

```
counter = collections.Counter(palavras)
mais_comuns = counter.most_common(20)
```